# Fourier Series Problem w/the Ramp Function

Tags: integration, fourier-series

In a book on Fourier Analysis:

[image]

**Question:** This assertion follows without proof. Why is it so? I see that if $n = 0$, then $e^{-i 0 \theta} = 1$, so that

$$
{1 \over 2 \pi} \int_{- \pi}^\pi \theta e^{-in\theta} d\theta = {1 \over 2 \pi} 0 = 0
$$

But what about when $n \ne 0$?